# Rows not aligned with DhtmlxScheduler and terrace skin on IE10

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scheduler, dhtmlx

I'm using DHTMLX.

I have a strange issue with the Scheduler on Internet Explorer 10. 
Every row hour there's a pixel added at the bottom of the line.

[Row display problem http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/199786Capture.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/199786Capture.png)

It only happens with the dhx_terrace skin.

On the other web browser there's the same behaviour when I load Twitter Bootstrap. 
But I achieved to fix it with :

```
div[class^='dhx_'], div[class*='dhx_']{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Strangely, this problem happens on Internet Explorer 10 even when Bootstrap is not loaded.

Has anyone ever experienced something like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's caused by page zoom. Check the value in IE settings, ctrl+0 to set default.

dhtmlxScheduler displays correctly with 100% zoom (default). 
When you apply different zoom level, sizes of some elements may slightly mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's been a long time since I had this problem and I don't remember exactly how I solved it, but I think it was indeed a zoom problem. I haven't been able to reproduce it now but I consider your answer is correct. Thanks